# Does entanglement mean that information travels faster than light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

Every time in physics (in popsci) I hear that it is not possible to travel faster than light, as this would cause many problems that I do not understand.

On the other side, in Quantum Computing (in advanced university classes) we have been told that the entanglement between two qubits means that if a measurement is made on one of them, the other one is decided instantaneously.

How is this? Does that information travel faster than light?

Since my background is computer science and I don't have much knowledge of physics, I would appreciate an explanation as simple as possible, or some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> entanglement between two qubits means that if a measurement is made on
> one of them, the other one is decided instantaneously.

This is true, but this does not allow for faster than light communication. If you have one qubit with you and i have one qubit with me and you make a measurement on your qubit, that will mean my qubit is decided . But how does that send any signal ?

Later on, when i make a measurement on my qubit, i get a measurement, just as i would have got some measurement had you not measured first. There is no way for me to know, i got this measurement after you had measured yours or before you have measured yours. Hence, no signal can be sent faster than light using entanglement